# Marcar checkbox se valor for igual a 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá!
Através da função abaixo:

```js
        success: function( tbl_permissao ) {
            obj_permissao = tbl_permissao;

            var permissoes = phpUnserialize(obj_permissao.permissoes);
            console.log(permissoes);

            $.each(permissoes, function (name, valor) {                 
                var $el = $('[name="' + name + '"]'),
                type = $el.attr('type');
                switch (type) {
                    case 'checkbox':                            
                     $el.prop('checked', true);                         
                     break;
                    case 'radio':
                     $el.filter('[value="' + valor + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
                     break;
                    default:
                    $el.valor(valor);
                }
            });

            obj_form();
            ret = true           
            $('#modal_permissao').modal('show');
            $('.modal-title').html('<i class="fa fa-lock "></i> Editar Permissão');
        },
```

Mais precisamento na linha
 `var permissoes = phpUnserialize(obj_permissao.permissoes);
console.log(permissoes);`

Eu obtenho o seguinte objeto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso agora **Marcar / Checar** os elementos do tipo checkbox, cujo `valor` for igual a **1**.

Utilizando a função abaixo, todos os elementos do tipo checkbox estão sendo marcados, então, podem me ajudar com isto e marcar somente se valor for igual a 1?

`<input name="aCliente" type="checkbox" >
 <input name="eCliente" type="checkbox" >
 <input name="dCliente" type="checkbox" >
 <input name="vCliente" type="checkbox" >`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a ideia é checkar os `<input>` com o `name` correspondente ao que vem no objeto a `1` pode fazer o seguinte:

```js
var permissoes ={ 
  aCliente : null,
  eCliente: 1,
  dCliente: 1,
  vCliente: null
};

for (var chave in permissoes){ //percorrer todos os campos do objeto
  if (permissoes[chave] == 1){ //ver se o campo vem a 1
    $("input[name=" + chave +"]").prop('checked', true); //por checked através de prop
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="aCliente" type="checkbox" >
 <input name="eCliente" type="checkbox" >
 <input name="dCliente" type="checkbox" >
 <input name="vCliente" type="checkbox" >
```

Comment: perfeito Isac,
Eu só retirei um sinal de igualdade para funcionar. `if (permissoes[chave] == 1)`

Comment: @WagnerFilho, sim é verdade no seu exemplo vem texto em vez de número. Nem tinha reparado

Answer (score 2):

Para marcar checkbox com jQuery, pode usar o `.prop('checked')`, e setar seu valor como `true` ou `false`

```js
$(document).delegate('#txtChecar','keyup',function (e) {
   //Verifica se o valor digitado foi igual a 1
   var deve_marcar = ($(this).val() == "1") ? true : false;
   $('#alvo').prop('checked', deve_marcar);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Digite 1 para marcar: <input type="text" id="txtChecar" maxlength="1"></input>
<br>
Alvo: <input id="alvo" type="checkbox" />
```